# Assign projection to hundreds of shapefiles using OGR2OGR

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to assign projection ESPG:32638 to hundreds of shapefiles in batch way like this

for %%N in (d:\lid\i08*.shp) DO ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:32638  d:\lid\i08\mod\%%N d:\lid\i08\%%N

however, this is not working

Any clues why it's not working?

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: for %%N in (d:\lid\i08\*.shp) DO (
 echo %%N
 ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:32638 d:\lid\i08\mod\%~nI %%N
) - gives me error susbtitution is invalid: %~nI d:\lid\i08\~nI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any easy way to do this is to download the required prj file from [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/32638.esriwkt) and then copy it to each shapefile.

```
for %%N in (d:\lid\i08*.shp) DO copy example.prj "%%~nN.prj"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, that's another angle that is simple and clever, I will try to make it work and report back.

Comment: worked fine thanks, on the command line, I rewrote as:- for %N in (d:\lid\i08\*.shp) DO copy example.prj "%~nN.prj"

Answer (score 0):

`%%N` contains the entire filename, including the path, so ogr2ogr is trying to write to  d:\lid\i08\mod\d:\lid\i08something.shp, which is not a valid filename To get just the filename, use `d:\lid\i08\mod\%%nxN`

Type `help for` to get more information about modifiers.

```
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
```

It usually helps to create a batchfile and add some logging:

```
@echo off
for %%N in (d:\lid\i08*.shp) DO (
    echo %%N
    ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:32638 d:\lid\i08\mod\%%N d:\lid\i08\%%N
)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I'm still trying to get it to work, and will let you know if it does.